Call an API endpoint with Laravel controller
My Laravel API is running on 127:0.0.1:8000.
Now I want to call to this API
Route::get('/task/{task_id}', [TaskDetailsController::class, 'index']);
from my web controller
This is the function where I wrote to call that API
public function index($task, $token)
    {
        $tokens = Token::where('token', $token)->first();
        $tasks = Task::find($task);
        $apiUrl = url('/api/task/'.$task);
        if ($tokens && $tasks){
            $response = Http::withHeaders([
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
            ])->get(''.$apiUrl);
            if ($response->successful()) {
                dd($response->json());
            } else {
                dd("failed");
            }
        }
        else{
            dd("baal");
        }
    }

but I get this error

cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 30002 milliseconds with 0 bytes received (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://localhost:8000/api/task/11

I have tried to write raw PHP code and use guzzle http package
but didn't get the fix.

why would you ever need to hit an endpoint on your application from WITHIN your application?

Laravel Http client is not used to make requests to own API.
Use for external API.
Learn the standard usage of Laravel.
You can use Eloquent directly.
// web controller

use App\Models\Task;

public function show(Task $task){
    return view('task.show')->with(compact('task'));
}

Use Sanctum before creating your own token system.
// routes/web.php

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')
     ->get('/task/{task}', [TaskDetailsController::class, 'show'])
     ->name('task.show');

Http client doesn't appear anywhere.
